# Asynchronus calls with analytics.js

Tags: google-analytics

I know how to use ga.js +async calls.

Does analytics.js defautly makes async calls?

What I want to know if it is possible to make calls with analytics.js + async ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Universal Analytics works asynchronously. The ga() method puts the arguments (i.e. which method to call and which parameters to pass to this method) on an array which is iterated and the item executed after analytics.js has loaded. The new code is just a little more oblique than ga.js because it uses a wrapper (ga()) instead of the native push method, but the way it works is not all that different.